# Replacing type in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB database where I'm trying to replace all arrays of a particular element with a concatenated string. Currently, most of the documents have an array of strings.  I need a script that will find each of the documents that have an array (some have been updated by hand already) and replace that array with a concatenation of what's currently there.

So far, I have:

```
var cursor = db.recipe.find({ directions: { $type : 4 } });
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    var doc = cursor.next();
    db.recipe.update(
        { _id : doc._id },
        { $set : { directions : { $concat : { doc.directions } } } }
    );
};
```

Unfortunately, it keeps complaining about an unexpected '.'.  I'm assuming that I'm using $concat incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat) is an aggregation operator. To simply find and update, use plain javascript.

> *Currently, most of the documents have an array of strings. I need a script that will find each of the documents that have an array*

When you apply `$type:4` to an array, it in turn checks if any of the elements inside the `directions` field is an array, only if it finds one it returns true.

eg: for input `["x","y"]` it would return `false`, and for `[["x"],"y"]` it would return `true`.

Since your array contains only strings, you need to use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-by-data-type) operator to find the type.

```
db.recipe.find({$where:"Array.isArray(this.directions)"}).forEach(function(doc){
var value = doc.directions.join();
db.recipe.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"directions":value}});
})
```